# Two dialog boxes using Deferreds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've two similar functions and I want to use one generic function with two params, `dialog` and `buttons`.  How do I do it?

My functions:

```
LanguageLogosView.showConfirmRemoveDialog = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var buttons = {
        buttons: {
            "Remove": function () {
                def.resolve(true);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                def.resolve(false);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    };
    $('#dialog-confirm-remove').dialog($.extend(LanguageLogosView.dialogConfirmDefaultSettings, buttons));
    return def;
}

LanguageLogosView.showConfirmEmptyRowsDialog = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var buttons = {
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                def.resolve(true);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                def.resolve(false);
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    };
    $("#dialog-confirm-save-with-empty-rows").dialog($.extend(LanguageLogosView.dialogConfirmDefaultSettings, buttons));
    return def;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, always return `def.promise()` - not `def` itself. If you return the Deferred object itself, other code can call `resolve/reject` on it. So keep `def` to yourself, and only return its promise.

Also, why not use `reject()` for the Cancel buttons instead of `resolve(false)`? If you use `reject`, it'll probably make the rest of your code simpler, since you don't need to check the resolve arguments. Your "success" handler either gets called, or it doesn't.

Second, since you're building buttons in both cases, that'd probably be the part I'd extract. For instance

```
function makeDialogButtons(resolveTitle, rejectTitle) {
  var def = $.Deferred(),
      buttons = {};

  buttons[resolveTitle] = function () {
    def.resolve();
    $(this).dialog('close');
  };

  buttons[rejectTitle] = function () {
    def.reject();
    $(this).dialog('close');
  };

  return { buttons: buttons, promise: def.promise() };
}
```

And use it like so

```
LanguageLogosView.showConfirmEmptyRowsDialog = function () {
  var buttons = makeDialogButtons('Save', 'Cancel');
      options = $.extend(LanguageLogosView.dialogConfirmDefaultSettings, buttons.buttons);
  $("#dialog-confirm-save-with-empty-rows").dialog(options);
  return buttons.promise;
};
```

It's not *great*, but it should do the job.

Comment: Thanks about returning promise, I've fixed my code already.

Comment: To @nrw who suggested an edit that got rejected: You were right. Unfortunately, the edit was rejected just 1 minute before I saw it, otherwise I would've approved it.